# Percent-encoding (URL encoding) does not work well in MS Word. Is there a fix?

Tags: microsoft-word

In a text written in MS Word 2002, I want to include this: http://hdl.handle.net/2027/uma.ark:/13960/t7fr05w6z?urlappend=%3Bseq=1363 permanent link, that points to one of the pages of an old magazine ([see HERE what a permanent link is good for](http://www.paradigm.ac.uk/workbook/metadata/pids.html)), behind the text: "Awards in Photographic Contest".

So, when I click the string "Awards in Photographic Contest" in MS Word, I want the page, the link points to, be opened.

However, instead of being sent to the page referenced by "seq=1363", MS Word opens a file positioned at the beginning of the magazine, which is wrong.

The only fix I found is to set the field "Text to display" as: 
http://hdl.handle.net/2027/uma.ark:/13960/t7fr05w6z?urlappend=%3Bseq=1363 with "%3B" instead of ";" and the Address to http://hdl.handle.net/2027/uma.ark:/13960/t7fr05w6z?urlappend=;seq=1363
(see the attached picture)

This approach is unacceptable because the "Text to display" must be "Awards in Photographic Contest". I tried to use "%3B" in "Address" but it does not work. It changes to ";".

Is there an acceptable fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, what worked was to use alt-F9 to reveal the field code for the HYPERLINK field and replace the ";" by "%3B" in there.

In both cases, the Hyperlink tooltip showed ";" in the link, but clicking the ";" version loaded the magazine at the beginning, whereas clicking the "%3B" version loaded the magazine at the specified point.

Here, when I inserted "%3B" in the *dialog box*, Word 2002 changed it to ";" in the HYPERLINK field that it inserts.

What I cannot be sure of is that this is entirely the fault of Word 2002. I am pretty sure that Word "calls out" either to Windows, IE, or perhaps even "the default browser" when it is working with hyperlinks. If so, it is likely that Word 2002 will behave differently on a different version of Windows/IE/browser.

However, I did try the same experiments with Word 2003 (on a slightly different Windows platform). The "%3B" and ";" links behaved exactly as they did on Word 2002. However, when I inserted "%3B" in the dialog box, Word 2003 retained the "%3B" in the HYPERLINK field.

Comment: In Word 2002, if I use Alt F9 to make the HYPERLINK field visible and then replace ";" by "%3B", press again Alt F9 to go back to the normal view and then try to open the link, it does not work. I am always sent to the beginning of the document also, in the HYPERLINK field, the "%3B" is retained.

Comment: You may also need to select the modified field and use F9 to update it.

Comment: Yes, with F9 for update it works. Thank you.